# Return a 1x1 Pixel in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I need the easiest way which costs the lowest server ressources to return a 1x1 pixel jpg image.

My idea is some kind of array, which contains the elements to be returned.

Answer (score 1):

Send the image as a BASE64-encoded string.

Comment: Hi Anders, yes that was the idea.So i generate  apixel with photoshop and open it with text editor?

Comment: No, you can't just send or base64 encode an image file in Photoshop format. Save it to gif from Photoshop and then convert that gif to base64 (for instance with an online service like this: https://www.base64-image.de/)